# convert json string with "\" to dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dictionary

I want to convert the following json string to dictionaly containing key-value pair

```
["\"TransferDate\" : \"05/30/2014\",\"Location\" : \"013\",\"VendorName\" : \"fdgfg\",\"VendorName_Other\" : \"\",\"Add1\" : \"\",\"Add2\" : \"\",\"Add3\" : \"\",\"City\" : \"\",\"State\" : \"\",\"Zip\" : \"\",\"Vphone\" : \"\",\"Vfax\" : \"\",\"Amount\" : \"$0.00\",\"Description\" : \"\",\"Comments\" : \"\",\"RequestBy\" : \"a den\",\"RPhone\" : \"\",\"FullName\" : \"dfgfg\",\"APhone\" : \"\",\"ReturnAddress\" : \"\",\"itemdesc\" : \"\",\"amount\" : \"\",\"account\" : \"\",\"accdesc\" : \"\",\"comments\" : \"\",\"assetno\" : \"\",\"category\" : \"\",\"internalorder\" : \"\",\"uom\" : \"\",\"Mail Check\":\"0\"",""]
```

Please suggest me how to do so, I am not able to figure out since the string which i get above is haing "\" character in it.

Comment: Using a JSON parser, perhaps?

Comment: Are you passing this string to asp.net web method using ajax ?

Comment: @karthik - No, I just need to convert it into dictionary key-value pair and then forward it to a method

Comment: Like others are saying below, this is not an array nor an object. It's not that " that are throwing the parser off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add `closure` at the beginning and at the end of your JSON string. You've it in array right now.

Now your json string will be

```
string str = "{ \"Location\" : \"013\",\"VendorName\" : \"fdgfg\",\"VendorName_Other\" : \"\",\"Add1\" : \"\" }";
```

I've just picked up a sample of your JSON.

Now just add the following line of code.

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(str);
```

This should do the job for you.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(YourJson);
```

Comment: Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'           I am getting this exception

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Json.NET and install the nuget package from the Package Manager Console

Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

and write code in cs file as below

```
string str = "[" + "\"TransferDate\" : \"05/30/2014\",\"Location\" : \"013\",\"VendorName\" : \"fdgfg\",\"VendorName_Other\" : \"\",\"Add1\" : \"\",\"Add2\" : \"\",\"Add3\" : \"\",\"City\" : \"\",\"State\" : \"\",\"Zip\" : \"\",\"Vphone\" : \"\",\"Vfax\" : \"\",\"Amount\" : \"$0.00\",\"Description\" : \"\",\"Comments\" : \"\",\"RequestBy\" : \"a den\",\"RPhone\" : \"\",\"FullName\" : \"dfgfg\",\"APhone\" : \"\",\"ReturnAddress\" : \"\",\"itemdesc\" : \"\",\"amount\" : \"\",\"account\" : \"\",\"accdesc\" : \"\",\"comments\" : \"\",\"assetno\" : \"\",\"category\" : \"\",\"internalorder\" : \"\",\"uom\" : \"\",\"Mail Check\":\"0\"" + "]";
            string json = str.Trim().Replace("[", "{").Replace("]", "}");
            Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```